# How to convert from NetworkX graph to ete3 Tree object?

Tags: python, tree, converters, networkx, ete3

I'm trying to figure out how to build an `ete3.Tree` object from a `networkx` directed graph?  I added each `child` in the way I thought would produce the desired result but I am having trouble.

```
edges = [('lvl-1', 'lvl-2.1'), ('lvl-1', 'lvl-2.2'), ('lvl-2.1', 'lvl-3.1'), ('lvl-2.1', 2), ('lvl-2.2', 4), ('lvl-2.2', 6), ('lvl-3.1', 'lvl-4.1'), ('lvl-3.1', 5), ('lvl-4.1', 1), ('lvl-4.1', 3), ('input', 'lvl-1')]
graph = nx.OrderedDiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw(graph, pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(graph, prog="dot"), with_labels=True, node_size=1000, node_color="lightgray")
```

[image]

```
tree = ete3.Tree()
for parent, children in itertools.groupby(graph.edges(), lambda edge:edge[0]):
    subtree = ete3.Tree(name=parent)
    for child in children:
        subtree.add_child(name=child[1])
    tree.add_child(child=subtree, name=parent)
print(tree) 
#       /-lvl-2.1
#    /-|
#   |   \-lvl-2.2
#   |
#   |   /-lvl-3.1
#   |--|
#   |   \-2
#   |
#   |   /-4
#   |--|
# --|   \-6
#   |
#   |   /-lvl-4.1
#   |--|
#   |   \-5
#   |
#   |   /-1
#   |--|
#   |   \-3
#   |
#    \- /-lvl-1
```

I've also tried the following but it did not work:

```
tree = ete3.Tree()
for parent, child in graph.edges():
    if parent not in tree:
        tree.add_child(name=parent)
    subtree = tree.search_nodes(name=parent)[0]
    subtree.add_child(name=child)
print(tree)
#                /-1
#             /-|
#          /-|   \-3
#         |  |
#       /-|   \-5
#      |  |
#    /-|   \-2
#   |  |
#   |  |   /-4
# --|   \-|
#   |      \-6
#   |
#    \- /-lvl-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Graph
edges = [('lvl-1', 'lvl-2.1'), ('lvl-1', 'lvl-2.2'), ('lvl-2.1', 'lvl-3.1'), ('lvl-2.1', 2), ('lvl-2.2', 4), ('lvl-2.2', 6), ('lvl-3.1', 'lvl-4.1'), ('lvl-3.1', 5), ('lvl-4.1', 1), ('lvl-4.1', 3), ('input', 'lvl-1')]
G = nx.OrderedDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# Tree
root = "input"
subtrees = {node:ete3.Tree(name=node) for node in G.nodes()}
[*map(lambda edge:subtrees[edge[0]].add_child(subtrees[edge[1]]), G.edges())]
tree = subtrees[root]
print(tree.get_ascii())
#                                /-1
#                         /lvl-4.1
#                  /lvl-3.1      \-3
#                 |      |
#           /lvl-2.1      \-5
#          |      |
# -inputlvl-1      \-2
#          |
#          |       /-4
#           \lvl-2.2
#                  \-6
```

Answer (score 0):

The subtrees and reading from networkX object are alright, the problem is that you're adding all subtrees to your original `tree` instance directly. In ete3, `Tree` class is [in fact just a Node](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html#understanding-ete-trees) (including pointers to its descendants, if any), so `tree.add_child` adds new child nodes/subtrees directly to the root node.

What you should do instead is [iterate over the leaves of ete tree](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html#browsing-trees-traversing), find the one where `node.name == parent` and attach all the children to it. Also, you should attach them one by one, not pre-generate a subtree. Otherwise you would get additional internal node with a single parent and a single child.

### EDIT:

The second version of your code is almost right, but you fail to consider that nodes are never to be attached to the tree (*ie* root) if the root isn't their actual parent. That's probably why you get `lvl-1` as a separate node which isn't a parent of other nodes. Also, I'm not sure about the networkX graph traversal order, which may be important. Safer (if uglier) version would look like this:

```
# Setting up a root node for lvl-1 to attach to
tree.add_child(name='input')
# A copy in a list, because you may not want to edit the original graph
edges = list(graph.edges)
while len(edges) > 0:
    for parent, child in edges:
        # check if this edge's parent is in the tree
        for leaf it tree.get_leaves(): 
            if leaf.name == parent:
                # if it is, add child and thus create an edge
                leaf.add_child(name=child)
            # Wouldn't want to add the same edge twice, would you?
            edges.remove((parent, child))
    # Now if there are edges still unplaced, try again.
```

There may be a couple of typos in there, and it's definitely super slow. Something around O(n**2) from edge count or worse, what with all the iteration and list removals. Probably there is a method to walk the graph from root to leaves, which wouldn't require a copy of the edge list (and will work in a single iteration). But it will eventually produce a correct tree.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Apologies, but I am still a little confused: (1) I thought that  I was obtaining each subtree collection by the incoming edge `itertools.groupby(graph.edges(), lambda edge:edge[0])`; (2) For iterating over the leaves, do you mean over the networkx nodes? ; (3) would I add `node.name == parent` to any part of my code or do I need restructure the code to handle (2) above.

Comment: Expanded the answer